# Javascript convert blob to string and back

Tags: javascript, filereader

I can convert a blob to string using FileReader, but I want to convert it back:

```
var reader = new window.FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
reader.onloadend = function() {
   base64data = reader.result;
   var blobToSend = base64data.substr(base64data.indexOf(',')+1);
   rtcMultiConnection.send({"command":{
       "recording":blobToSend,
       "type":blob.type,
       "size":blob.size
   }});
}
```

This is sent with https://github.com/muaz-khan/RTCMultiConnection but the main question is how to reconstruct the blob after being sent. Sadly sending the blob as is didn't work.

Comment: Chrome supports array-buffer, and RTCMultiConection support it as well. Blob-support in chrome is work-in-progress. So for now, you can use "fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer". For your information, this will work: `connection.send(recorder.blob)` RTCMultiConnection will auto share the entire blob (of any size). Remote users will receive the complete blob in "onFileEnd" event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

source: [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)
This method correctly converts back base64 data to the original binary data.
For the sake of performance improvements, the data is processed in blocks of the size of sliceSize.
NOTE: source is in TypeScript

```
    public static Base64ToBlob(b64Data, contentType = "", sliceSize = 512): Blob
    {
        const byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        const byteArrays = [];

        for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize)
        {
            const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);
            const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);

            for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++)
            {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
        return blob;
    }
```